# ExtJS 4.2 attach event in view to other views

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a view with the following in my `initComponent`:

```
    initComponent: function() {
            var me = this;

            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                buttons: [
                         {
                             text: 'Guardar',
                             action: 'commit',
                             glyph: Glyphs.SAVE
                         }
                ],
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'shiftpattern.window.formcode',
                    height: 50
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'shiftpattern.window.grid',
                    flex: 1
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'shiftpattern.window.formpattern',
                    height: 180
                }
                ]
            });


            // here i need to listen to the grid's selectionchange event
            me.on('selectionchange', me.onGridSelectionChange, me);
            me.callParent(arguments);
        },
 onGridSelectionChange: function(grid, records) {
        console.log('daysoff grid selection');
        var me = this,
            record = records[0];


    }
```

I know that I can do that inside a controller, but in this case this view has it'w own behavior and I can reuse it in my sections of my application.

Is there a way to insert a selector to `me.on('selectionchange', me.onGridSelectionChange, me);`

> Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it:

```
me.on('selectionchange', me.onGridSelectionChange, me);
```

has to go after:

```
me.callParent(arguments);
```